# PHP Serialize Successful, Unserialize Failure

Tags: php, forms, serialization

My PHP code serializes, but doesn't unserialize, what could be the problem?

```
$serializedColumns = serialize($columnNames);
```

I have the following resulting html, where i stored the serialized string into a hidden field:

```
<input id="columns_hidden" name="columns" type="hidden" value="a:3:{i:0;s:8:&quot;Username&quot;;i:1;s:8:&quot;Password&quot;;i:2;s:11:&quot;AccessLevel&quot;;}">
```

The request is sent to 'AddData.php', i where i have my unserialize code like this:

```
$columns =  unserialize($_REQUEST['columns']);
```

when i call `print_r` on `$columns`, it returns a blank string.

when i call `print_r` on `$_REQUEST['columns']`, it returns:

`a:3:{i:0;s:8:\"Username\";i:1;s:8:\"Password\";i:2;s:11:\"AccessLevel\";}`

Comment: What is `print_r($_REQUEST['columns']);` saying?

Comment: The `:` in front of `{` at the beginning is missing: `a:3{` is wrong, must be `a:3:{` instead, but you should not use serialize for what you do. [Explanation and alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680956/php-serialize-successful-unserialize-failure/7681046#7681046).

Comment: That is an extreme security hole you've got there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a comment, but I put it here for more attention: **Don't do that**.

*Why?* - Whenever you `unserialize` data provided by a request blindly, PHP does more than you think. This can create objects which are dangerous for your application and you can not do a thing against that.

The hidden input can be easily edited and manipulated with a DOM editor or JavaScript to include harmful code or malicious requests can be fired against your site bringing it down quickly.

*Alternatives* - Instead use some form of data that you can process more easily, for example, use `json_encode` / `json_decode` or a classic `implode` / `explode`:

```
$serializedColumns = implode(',', $columnNames);
```

and

```
$columns =  explode(',', $_REQUEST['columns']);
```

this is much more failsafe and sane because it's *static* data processing.

Comment: Thanks, i have decided to go with json_encode, and json_decode.

Answer (score 3):

It appears **you are passing the result of serialize through htmlspecialchars**. This will corrupt the serialized data. Use a different encoding method to make it safe for use as an html attribute value, i.e., [base64_encode](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php):

```
<?php
$serializedColumns = serialize($columnNames);
?>

<input id="columns_hidden" name="columns" type="hidden" value="<?php echo base64_decode($serializedColumns) ?>">
```

Then, in your processing script:

```
$columns =  unserialize(base64_decode($_REQUEST['columns']));
```

Comment: Why does it corrupt the serialized data?

Comment: Why? And with the data given in the question, it's not the string length that is causing this, but a missing `:`. However, I do not see how `htmlspecialchars` should have caused that. See the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

The `&quot;` are probabably going in the way of serialize, as the `;` is not escaped.

You could `base64_encode` the value and decode it afterwards:

```
$serializedColumns = base64_encode(serialize($columnNames));
```

to

```
$columns =  unserialize(base64_decode($_REQUEST['columns']));
```

Comment: The request variables don't have html-entities in there.

Answer (score 0):

when your data is posted to PHP, it looks like good old magic quotes is injecting \ before all the delimiting quote marks. You have to unescape it (drop slashes) before you can decode/unserialize.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VARCHAR for that column, try to change your MySQL column to TEXT.