# PHP Serialize html content

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, serialization, base64

I have a page that retrieves from a mysql db (blob) a serialized base64 encoded array, which is then decoded, unserialized, and displayed.

My problem is, any html that is displayed is as plain text (not as code) and the some of the sensitive characters are escaped. " for example is \". I tried adding a str_replace() and although it did remove the \'s it didn't solve the issue.

Here's the code that displays the info:

```
 $array = unserialize(base64_decode($sArray));
 if ($array != ''){
   foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
     echo "<td>$value</td>";
     }
 echo "</tr>";
 }
```

It properly adds the td tags to add to the table, but again, the $value is displayed as plain text.

Thanks in advance for any help!

The array is setup something like this:

```
 FieldTitle1 => <a href="#">link</a>
 FieldTitle2 => Random Text
 FieldTitle3 => 930809830
```

Sample sArray data:

```
  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
```

Comment: please give some sample data $sArray

Comment: and what is the outcome of the script? what is the source that is generated?

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680956/php-serialize-successful-unserialize-failure

Comment: @Eyal Alsheich - it's adding a saved list of data to a table.

Comment: what do you mean $value shows as plain text? what is the end result of this script, after you get the array unserialzed?

Comment: @Eyal Alsheich - THANKS FOR THAT LINK! I changed form serialization to json_encode/decode and that solved the issue!

Comment: Those slashes don't appear out of nowhere, they've been added to the data at some point *before* it was stored! Fix that process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed form serialization to json_encode/decode and that solved the issue!

[PHP Serialize Successful, Unserialize Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680956/php-serialize-successful-unserialize-failure)

Thanks @Eyal Alsheich for pointing this link out!